# Returning a value to Java from a Swig C function

Tags: java, c, swig

I'm struggling to understand the syntax of .i files in Swig.
Even for something as simple as passing a parameter by address in C, I can't find the correct call in Java.
So my C function:

```
void SimpleReturn(int *w) {
    *w = 3;
}
```

My Swig file:

```
%module MYtest
%{
#include "MYtest.h"
%}
%include "arrays_java.i"
%apply double[] {double *}; // WTF does this mean ?!?
// Parse the header file to generate wrappers. Why is this here again ?!?
%include "MYtest.h"
```

And my Java:

```
import net.hep.ami.utility.n2edm.*;
public class main {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        System.loadLibrary("MYtest_swig");  // File is libMYtest_swig.so

        int r;
        net.hep.ami.utility.n2edm.MYtest.SimpleReturn(r);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

I've re-read section 26.3.10 of http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Java.html#Java_pointers_refs_arrays and it seems so simple but I can't get it to work.

```
main.java:22: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to SWIGTYPE_p_int
                net.hep.ami.utility.n2edm.AMItest.SimpleReturn(r);
```

Comment: Is it because it's an `int` instead of a `Foo` like in the example ?

Comment: No, it expects a pointer to an int, `SWIGTYPE_p_int`, you provide an int (by-value).